# Settings panel missing from Explore Mode

Tags: experience-editor

In Experience Editor, when I switch a page to Explore mode, I do not see the Settings panel that is referenced in all of Sitecore's documentation on the subject.

- https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/explore_mode/explore_mode
- https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/explore_mode/using_explore_mode/explore_mode_settings

I've looked through the source of the Experience Editor page to see if I could find it (I thought it might be hidden behind part of our page with a `z-index` or something), but I couldn't find anything.

Anyone know what might be causing it to hide?

Comment: Can you try to switch to Preview and then back to Explore mode?

Comment: @PeterProchazka I've tried that and it still doesn't show any evidence of Explore mode (admittedly, I can't really switch back to preview mode without using the back button because the ribbon isn't visible in Explore mode, either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check the source of the page in Experience Editor, you should see at the bottom of the body a `<div class="experience-explorer">`.

It contains a `<a class="trigger">` link and iframe linking to `/sitecore modules/web/experienceexplorer/Controls/ExpEditor.aspx` page.

You need to click on the arrow trigger link to show the settings panel (see screenshot):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Marek! It turns out we have some styles that are hiding the `.panel` CSS class which causes the arrow buttons to disappear.